# How to show that there are infinitely many prime numbers $p$ such that the polynomial f has a zero in $\mathbb Z_p$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, finite-fields, distribution-of-primes

Let $f\in \mathbb Z[X]$ be a polynomial of positive degree.How to show that there are infinitely many prime numbers $p$ such that the polynomial $f$ has a zero in $\mathbb Z/p \mathbb Z$ ?

I have no idea of how to start even.

Need help

Comment: By $\Bbb{Z}_p$ do you mean the $p$-adic integers or the field of $p$ elements?

Comment: @Servaes:See the edit

Comment: That edit wasn't too helpful :)

Comment: @darijgrinberg:I mean a field with p elements

Comment: Ah, I fixed it.

Comment: It would help your cause to provide some context. As per [our guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619). Also, did you search the site? This may well be a dupicate of an older question!

Comment: To all future voters on this thread. The question is sub-par. But Carl Schildkraut's nice answer is worth preserving. I think merging this to the chosen dupe target (or to another answer linked to my pick, if judged better) would be a possibility. Carl's answer will defend its place among those older answers quite well if you ask me.

Comment: A merger may raise some notational compatibility issues. Unless I missed something here that would be limited to denoting the polynomial with $g$ instead of $f$. Ping me, if you choose to merge, and want help wih such edits.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: Assume there are finitely many primes that divide any values of $f$. Then, for all $n$,

$$f(n)=\pm p_1^{e_1}\cdots p_k^{e_k}$$

for some nonnegative integers $e_1,\cdots,e_k$.

If you look at the range $[-N,N]$ for some large $N$, what proportion of numbers in that range are values of $f$ (asymptotically)? What proportion of those numbers can be written as $\pm p_1^{e_1}\cdots p_k^{e_k}$?

Comment: :By proportion do you mean number of divisors of $f(n)$?

Comment: Carl Schildkraut:$\frac{\tau (f(n))}{N}$?,Where $\tau (f(n))$ means number of positive divisors of $f(n).$

Comment: @Damon not quite. I mean what proportion of integers in the range $[-N,N]$ can be written as $f(n)$ for some integer $n$. E.g. for $f(x)=x^2+1$ and $N=30$ only the values $\{1,5,10,17,26\}$ can be reached, which is $$\frac{5}{2\cdot 30+1}=\frac{5}{61}$$ of the number of integers in the interval itself.

Comment: @Damon Try to bound the range of those exponents $e_i$ using the logarithm of $N$. Then do the same for the values of $f$, this time using a relevant root of $N$. Then remember what you know about the asymptotics of $\log N$ vs. $N^\alpha,\alpha>0$, as $N\to\infty$.